# How to create sequence numbering with leading zeros using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hi GAS/Javascript experts,

I found the script to auto-generate sequential IDs starts from which number we defined in a variable : [Auto sequence ID](https://howtogapps.com/google-sheets-script-for-auto-numbering-google-form-responses/)
However, I need to add 3 leading zeros to make sure the number of digits will be standardized to 6 digits in total inclusive the generated IDs. eg. 000100, 000101, 000102, 000103, ....
And if so happens that the data rows will be more than 999999, the subsequence digit should automatically be added to be 7 digits and so forth.

Anyone can help to amend the script to achieve the above objectives, please? Tqvm.

The current script is as follows :-

```
function addAutoNumber() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  // Get the last row that has content.
  var LastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Set the first Auto Number
  var AutoNumberStart=000100;  
  
  //---- First run ------------
  
  //Check if the first column is Timestamp
  if (sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue() == "Timestamp") {
    // insert a column to the left and the text "Auto Number" in the first row
    sheet.insertColumnBefore(1);
    sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue("Auto Number");
    // Fix for (probably) a bug that formats the new column 
    // with the same format of the column used to insert it,
    // in this case the column gets the date format like the Timestamp column.
    // So we set the format to number
    sheet.getRange("A2:A").setNumberFormat(0); 
    // check if there are already form responses and add numbers for them
    if (LastRow>1) {
      for(var ii=2; ii <= LastRow; ii++) {
        sheet.getRange(ii, 1).setValue(AutoNumberStart);
        AutoNumberStart++;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // ---- Add new Auto Number ----------
  
  // Check if there is a Number in the AutoNumber column 
  // for the last Form Submission
  if (sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1).isBlank()) {
  // Check if it is the first Form submission and set the AutoNumberStart
    if (LastRow == 2) {
      sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1).setValue(AutoNumberStart);
    } else {
      // Get the Last AutoNumber from the previous row
      var LastAutoNumber = sheet.getRange(LastRow-1, 1).getValue();
      // Set the next AutoNumber
      sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1).setValue(LastAutoNumber+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sheet.getRange("A2:A").setNumberFormat(0);
```

has to be

```
sheet.getRange("A2:A").setNumberFormat("000000");
```

For the autoupdating on higher entries, you have to add a listener to update it on changes to that column or update the numberFormat value to the largest number length on a new entry.

This can be done on your check where you add a new line:

```
const highestLen = (LastAutoNumber+1).toFixed(0).length;
if (highestLen > sheet.getRange("A2:A").getNumberFormat().length) {
  // depending on the length, this returns "000000", "0000000" and so on.
  const format = new Array(highestLen).fill("0").join("");
  sheet.getRange("A2:A").setNumberFormat(format);
}
```

Comment: Tqvm, @Christopher !. It works like a charm! Just that I changed the last line of ur code from ```"A2:A"``` to ```"A"+LastRow+":A"``` because I don't want to change the previous number of digits. ;)